# How to determine the number of factors in principle component analysis (PCA) when scree plot is ambiguous?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I've been running PCA using SPSS and here are the things I have done so far:

1. N = 105. The number isn’t exactly ideal for PCA and accordingly to majority of the studies, but I did find a few sources which claim that at least 100 is okay.
2. All 38 items of both EQ and QCAE questionnaires were chosen (these two scales measure empathy)
3. The Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin measure of sampling adequacy indicated a value of 0.73, which was above the recommended value of 0.5.
4. Bartlett’s test of sphericity was significant (suitable for data reduction).
5. To identify problematic variables, KMO statistics for individual variables were examined from the anti-image matrix. All of the variables had correlation above 0.5 and thus no problematic variables were found.
6. Average communalities had a value of 0.65, which was adequate for a sample size between 100 and 200 (MacCallum et al., 1999).
7. To choose an appropriate number of factors to extract, I used Kaiser’s eigenvalue criterion (>1) and thus retained 10 factors.
8. Ten factors in combination explained 65% of the variance, which is ok good
9. I used varimax rotation method to extract component matrix

Here are my problems:
#Problem 1: Upon the inspection of scree plot, points of reflects were observed at both 2 and 3 factors. It was not really aligned with the convergence of Kaiser’s criterion, but the rule itself has received a lot of criticisms of course. What do I do? (See the image)

[image]

#Problem 2: After an examination of the matrix, I started to think that the I should have just retained 2 factors, but the two-factor component would only explain 29.53% of the total variance, which is quite low. However, you can already see that cognitive empathy (online simulation, perspective taking) had a large representation in the factor loading, while mixing with a few EQ items. I have to think of something to explain this qualitatively of course..

Based on these problems, how can I determine the correct numbers of factors in my PCA?

[image]

Comment: Your scree plot elbow (Cattell) criterion suggests to try 4, 5, 6 factor solutions. Also, are you sure you want just PCA and not real FA?

Comment: You should not just "retain" components or factors in the rotated solution. If you re-decide on the number m of latents to extract you should re-do the analysis with this new number m, and rotate/interpret all the m.